# Python: What to put in __init__.py files if I'm using several subpackages?

Tags: python-3.x, initialization, python-import, setup-project

I buily a package with a folder structure like the following:

```
MyPackage
|
├──mypackage
|     |
|     ├── __init__.py
|     |
|     ├── config.py
|     |
|     ├── data_clean
|     |   ├── __init__.py
|     |   └── f1.py
|     |
|     ├── data_transform
|     |   ├── __init__.py
|     |   └── g1.py
|     |
|     └── stat_calc
|         ├── __init__.py
|         ├── s1.py
|         └── command_line_interface.py # <- users will use this from cmd.exe
| 
├── README.txt    
|
└── setup.py
```

All 4 `__init__.py` files are empty. Originally, when I wanted `s1.py` to use a function in `g1.py`, I would do

```
import mypackage.data_transform.g1
```

and then somewhere down the line I would do

```
mypackage.data_transform.g1.my_func()
```

Then, to save, space I changed all of the imports to look like

```
from mypackage.data_transform.g1 import my_func
```

and then I would use `my_func` somewhere. This new syntax is getting a lot of errors, I'm not sure what I should do or if/what I should put stuff into the `__init__.py` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 3.3+, `__init__.py` files are not necessary. After I removed all of the `__init__.py` files from my script, everything worked well with just:

```
from mypackage.data_transform.g1 import my_func
```